# Twitter at-reply not showing in search

Tags: twitter

When I send an @-tweet to someone it is not showing up in the search. Like "Hey @abc ... " and I type "@abc" in the search there are a bunch of tweets, but not mine.

My account is new, email activated and I tweeted some normal tweets. Why is it not working?